# Trying to change all text tables in PPT slides to text color and cell fill color?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to loop through all slides in a powerpoint and change whatever text tables there are in each slide to a blue color and black text.

getting a compile error here on the `.font.color`  line

```
Sub TableAllBlueandBlack()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape

With ActivePresentation
    For Each osld In .Slides
        For Each oShp In oSdl.Shapes
            Set oTbl = oShp.Table
                With oTbl
                    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241) 
                                    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                                End With
                            Next
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        Next
End With
End Sub
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `oSdl` in `oSdl.Shapes` is a typo, it should be `osld` (`Dim osld As Slide`). Using `Option Explicit` to avoid this kind of problem.
- Using `.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color` to update font color
- Check if the shape is a table with `oShp.HasTable`, otherwise `oShp.HasTable` may raise error.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub TableAllBlueandBlack()
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim lCol As Integer
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    With ActivePresentation
        For Each oSld In .Slides
            For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes '**
                If oShp.HasTable Then '**
                    Set oTbl = oShp.Table
                    With oTbl
                        For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241)
                                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) '**
                                End With
                            Next
                        Next
                    End With
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Shape` doesn't have a `Font` property.  You could use:

`.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)`

You might consider splitting up your code a little to reduce the deep nesting:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TableAllBlueandBlack()
    Dim oSld As Slide, oShp As Shape
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
            If oShp.HasTable Then _
                ReformatTable oShp.Table, RGB(211, 225, 241), vbBlack
        Next oShp
    Next oSld
End Sub

Sub ReformatTable(tbl As Table, fillColor As Long, textColor As Long)
    Dim rw As Row, c As Cell
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            With c.Shape
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = fillColor
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = textColor
            End With
        Next c
    Next rw
End Sub
```